# cleaner way to make a row of images with hover image change?

Tags: html, css, image, flexbox

I would like to know if there is a more cleaner/efficient way to make this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/L53e840z/4/. The issue with this is that that if if the window is made smaller or bigger there is this white space in between the images because it's dependent on it parent width. To make it work the parent is also set to an oddly specific 'vw' measurement that breaks if the arrangement is changed, I wanted it the images to stay proportional with 100% height of window with no whitespace and the parent to automatically adjust it's width to cover all child elements. I'm new to web dev and want to know the best practice to work with images.

What I made  explained ->
It's a container within which there is a parent element inside that there is a wrapper set to flex. Inside that wrapper are 6 image wrappers - inside each of these are 2 images set to absolute so they overlap one another. On hover, the front image fades and reveals the back.

HTML

```
<div id="stills-ba" data-tab-content>
            <div class="stills-ba">
               <div class="still-wrapper-ba">
                  <img class="front-img" loading="lazy" src="https://www.placecage.com/200/300" alt="still front">
                  <img class="back-img" loading="lazy" src="https://www.placecage.com/c/200/300" alt="still back">
               </div>
               <div class="still-wrapper-ba">
                  <img class="front-img" loading="lazy" src="https://www.placecage.com/200/300" alt="still FRONT">
                  <img class="back-img" loading="lazy" src="/https://www.placecage.com/c/200/300">
               </div>
               <div class="still-wrapper-ba">
                  <img class="front-img" loading="lazy" src="https://www.placecage.com/200/300" alt="still front">
                  <img class="back-img" loading="lazy" src="https://www.placecage.com/c/200/300">
               </div>
               <div class="still-wrapper-ba">
                  <img class="front-img" loading="lazy" src="https://www.placecage.com/200/300">
                  <img class="back-img" loading="lazy" src="https://www.placecage.com/c/200/300">
               </div>
               <div class="still-wrapper-ba">
                  <img class="front-img" loading="lazy" src="https://www.placecage.com/200/300">
                  <img class="back-img" loading="lazy" src="https://www.placecage.com/c/200/300" alt="still 1">
               </div>
               <div class="still-wrapper-ba">
                  <img class="front-img" loading="lazy" src="https://www.placecage.com/200/300">
                  <img class="back-img" loading="lazy" src="https://www.placecage.com/c/200/300" alt="still back">
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
```

CSS

```
#stills-ba {
   width: 200vw;
   height: 100vh;
}

.stills-ba {
   display: -webkit-box;
   display: -ms-flexbox;
   display: flex;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;

}
.still-wrapper-ba {
   position: relative;
   display: -webkit-box;
   display: -ms-flexbox;
   display: flex;
   width: 33vw;
   height: 100vh;
}

.front-img {
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   height: 100%;
   width: auto;
   -webkit-transition: opacity ease 250ms;
   -o-transition: opacity ease 250ms;
   transition: opacity ease 250ms;

}

.back-img {
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   height: 100%;
   width: auto;
   opacity: 1;
   z-index: -5;
}

.front-img:hover {
   opacity: 0;
}
```

Comment: i might not see something here, but couldnt you just set the width of the images to 100%? So .front-img and .back-img 100% instead of auto width

Comment: doesn't that make the images stretch wierdly? I wanted a way that preserves aspect ratio but doesn't cause whitespace

Comment: ah alright, didnt fully understand that sorry :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, the only problem comes from the white spaces between each photo when the screen is resized? Here is a solution: https://jsfiddle.net/cu0L87wr/

```css
#stills-ba {
  height: 100vh;
}

.stills-ba {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.still-wrapper-ba {
  position: relative;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
}

.front-img {
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  -webkit-transition: opacity ease 250ms;
  -o-transition: opacity ease 250ms;
  transition: opacity ease 250ms;
}

.back-img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: -5;
}

.front-img:hover {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
    <div id="stills-ba" data-tab-content>
      <div class="stills-ba">
        <div class="still-wrapper-ba">
          <img
            class="front-img"
            loading="lazy"
            src="https://www.placecage.com/200/300"
            alt="still front"
          />
          <img
            class="back-img"
            loading="lazy"
            src="https://www.placecage.com/c/200/300"
            alt="still back"
          />
        </div>
        <div class="still-wrapper-ba">
          <img
            class="front-img"
            loading="lazy"
            src="https://www.placecage.com/200/300"
            alt="still FRONT"
          />
          <img
            class="back-img"
            loading="lazy"
            src="https://www.placecage.com/c/200/300"
          />
        </div>
        <div class="still-wrapper-ba">
          <img
            class="front-img"
            loading="lazy"
            src="https://www.placecage.com/200/300"
            alt="still front"
          />
          <img
            class="back-img"
            loading="lazy"
            src="https://www.placecage.com/c/200/300"
          />
        </div>
        <div class="still-wrapper-ba">
          <img
            class="front-img"
            loading="lazy"
            src="https://www.placecage.com/200/300"
          />
          <img
            class="back-img"
            loading="lazy"
            src="https://www.placecage.com/c/200/300"
          />
        </div>
        <div class="still-wrapper-ba">
          <img
            class="front-img"
            loading="lazy"
            src="https://www.placecage.com/200/300"
          />
          <img
            class="back-img"
            loading="lazy"
            src="https://www.placecage.com/c/200/300"
            alt="still 1"
          />
        </div>
        <div class="still-wrapper-ba">
          <img
            class="front-img"
            loading="lazy"
            src="https://www.placecage.com/200/300"
          />
          <img
            class="back-img"
            loading="lazy"
            src="https://www.placecage.com/c/200/300"
            alt="still back"
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

I removed the width property from the wrapper (`#stills-ba`) and the absolute position of `.front-img`.